# How do I change the GTK (the gui) theme in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, themes, openbox

So I upgraded from 10.04 to 12.10, and somehow changing GTK themes (from ubuntu-tweak, gnome-tweak-tool etc) can't seem to change the archaic-looking rendering in:

[image]

into the selected theme. Am I missing something?

Update: another detail I forgot to mention is that I'm using OpenBox as opposed to the normal window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Openbox, then it is likely that `gnome-settings-daemon` should be started when you run any GTK+ applications. However, as this does not always happen, you may need to run it manually. Once you do, your applications will pick up the theme they are supposed to have.

You can add it to your Openbox session as a start-up application to make this persistent.